# how to select the main checkboxlist according to the sub checkboxlist in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist and it contains some items such as

- 100
- 100.001
- 100.002
- 100.003
- 200
- 200.001
- 200.002
- 200.003

these items have relationship between them. the parent items are 100 and 200.

100.001 , 100.002 and 100.003 are children of 100. and same for the items starts with 200

Lets say all items are UNSELECTED, for example, when user selects 100.002, I need to automatically select the parent which is 100.

what is a good way to that without looping?

here is my code

```
 private void clb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int selected = clb.SelectedIndex;
    // I need to get the selected item's Text
    // then I have to split it with   
    // string s = item.Text.Split('.')

    clb.SetItemChecked(clb.FindStringExact(s[0]), true);
 }
```

I am almost done with the above code, but I couldnt get the last selected item's text

Comment: Seems like you're using the wrong control, you should be using a TreeView rather than a checkbox list given that your data is a tree based structure.  This with both have a more sensible UI for your users, and make it easier for you, in code, to get the "parent" of a node, or the children of a given node.

Comment: I guess your `CheckBoxList` has some `Items` property and you can use `Items[selected]` or simply it should have some property called `SelectedItem`. Looks like it's a `DevExpress` control?

Comment: but I need users to select/check the items...

Comment: It is devexpress control

Comment: @ayilmaz so, look for the properties I suggested, I've used some DevExpress controls before but it's a long time ago.